# Error doesnt get displayed in span tag on form submit in html - Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, forms

I am new to jquery. I am trying to create a form in which if the user does not enter username the user will get a error. I have created a form which has input text, a span tag and a button. If i click on the button and the username field, the span tag should be visible.

My HTML code looks like:

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <script src="jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="check1.js"></script>
```

```
<body>      
  <div>
    <form id="myform" method="post">
            <table border="1">
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <input type="text" id="uname"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <span class="error">please enter data</span>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <button id="check"> submit</button>                      
                </td>
              </tr>
            </table>
    </form>
  </div>                
</body>
```

My style.css file:

```
.error
{
    visibility: hidden;
}

.error_show
{
    visibility: visible;
    color: red;

}
```

And the JQuery file:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#myform").on("submit", function(){
        var uname = $("#uname").val();
        if(uname == "")
        {
            $(".error").addClass("error_show");
        }
    });

});
```

I have used form submit in JQuery. The error gets diaplayed for less than a second. Why is that happening? Is there anything wrong in the code?

Comment: Use `return false;` or `event.preventDefault();` in `if`

Comment: because form is getting submitted.nothing is wrong in your code it behaves like it should

Answer (score 2):

disable the default behaviour of `submit` event with `preventDefault()`

```
  $("#myform").on("submit", function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
          ....rest of your code     
    });
```

Comment: thanks a lot! it worked. Can you explain what exactly does e.preventDefault(); does?

Comment: @AniruddhJhavar it cancels out the default behaviour of any event  https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault

Answer (score 1):

You should do you validation on the click event of the submit button, then if it passes call submit on the form itself.

Also, notice the `e.preventDefault()`. This prevents the form from submitting before you tell it to.

```
$("#check").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var uname = $("#uname").val();
    if(uname == "")
    {
        $(".error").addClass("error_show");
    } else {
        $("#myform").submit();
    }
});
```

Comment: Is form on submit not preferred or is there any other reason why you used button click?

Comment: This is really the main reason, to do validation *before* the form is submitted, while in your method the form has been submitted and you need to cancel it if validation fails. Better to check first.